# jQuery compare two DOM object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, object, compare

Clicking on an element:

```
$('.my_list').click(function(){
   var selected_object = $(this);

   $('.my_list').each(function(){
      var current_object = $(this);

      if( selected_object == current_object ) alert('FOUND IT !');
   });
});
```

I don't know why, but I don't get the alert message "FOUND IT !".

Comment: try using === and see

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use the [`jQuery.is`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) function:

> Check the current matched set of elements against a selector, element,
>   or jQuery object and return true if at least one of these elements
>   matches the given arguments.

```
if (selected_object.is(current_object)) {
   ...    
}
```

An alternate solution is to use [`jQuery.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) function to get the raw elements and compare them using `==` or `===` operator:

```
if (selected_object.get(0) == current_object.get(0)) {
   ...
}
```

[**jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/y8K22/)

Answer (score 3):

There's good answer provided... but it's important to understand, why you directly can't compare selectors in jQuery.

jQuery selectors return **data structures which will never be equal** in the sense of reference equality. So the only way to figure this out is to get DOM reference from the jQuery object and to compare DOM elements.

The simplest comparison of DOM reference for the above example would be:

```
selected_object.[0] == current_object.[0]
```